# How to show ranks in SSRS footer

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am using SSRS 2012 in which I am developing a report of type Matrix. User specify which categories (row header) and cities (columns header) he wants to appear in report, which we have handled by passing parameters to report.

The value in the reports are appearing after applying some formulas which we are handling in stored procedure.

I am stuck were I need to show ranks under each city in footer. Rank depends on sum of values for all categories related to a city.

Example:

```
       City-1  City-2  City-3  
Cat-1    50      20      40
Cat-2    10      30      40
==============================  
Rank      2       3       1
```

Comment: Does it have to be in the footer?

Comment: If I understand your problem, can you write an expression that says something like `SUM(IIF(Fields!cat-1.value + Fields!City-2.value,"1",nothing)` and repeat for every Rank you need?

Comment: @molleyc: 
not in footer, but it has to be at the bottom and with little different formatting

Comment: @Geo:
can you explain the formula little bit, I di not understand how i can mention cat-1 or city-2 user might select some other category or another city

Comment: better include your expected result in question thanks.

Comment: @MarcoBong I believe his expected result is the example. If you are explaining that the Cities and Categories are being selected through a parameter, then, based on a calculation, a rank is produced. Is the rank produced through an Expression/Calculation or is it a column in your database?

Comment: thats mean rank depends on Sum of City (cat1+cat2) ? if is, then it should be calculation part in your database(sql query)

Comment: @MarcoBong: Considering that I have to use matrix report to produce this output and the data which i am getting from DB (shown below):
 
    `City-1    Cat-1    50
    `City-1    Cat-2    10
    `City-2    Cat-1    20
    `City-2    Cat-2    30

I cannot think of a query which can show this data and calculate respective ranks.

Comment: As last option i will create another dataset in my report just to calculate ranks and place and table control below the matrix control to produce this output, one data set for matric showing city & category data, . I hope this works i.e. ranks will appear correctly below respective cities

Comment: @AbdulMohsin Solved.

Comment: @AbdulMohsin I like your idea (even if it feels like a hack...) Just make sure that the same Cities are included in your "Ranks" dataset, create the Ranks Matrix the same as the main Matrix, and hide the header row that would re-display the City names.

Answer (score 0):

Query :

```
declare @tb as Table (City int,Cat int, Score int)
insert into @tb select 1,1,50
union select 1,2,10
union select 2,1,20
union select 2,2,30
union select 3,1,40
union select 3,2,40

select h.*,d.Rank from @tb h
inner join 
(select City,SUM(Score) as TotalScore,ROW_NUMBER() 
over (order by SUM(Score) desc) as Rank from @tb group by City ) d 
on h.City = d.City
```

SSRS Table Design :

[image]

Result :

[image]